# android thread / Task basics help please?

Tags: android, multithreading

ok so im very new to android development and fairly new to java and i dont fully understand threads and inner classes and such.
i have my main activity (MyActivity) with all my ui stuff in it.
i have an inner class (MyTask) extends AsyncTask with a thread running that changes the ui

```
public final class MyActivity extends Activity{
blah..
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void>{
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {

             t = new Thread(){
                 @Override
                public void run() {
                  while(true) {
//do ui change stuff here
```

this works fine.

i would like to play a sound using AudioTrack in streaming mode that is triggered by the events in MyTask.
however this will interfere with the ui stuff.
whats the best way to handle the sound playing code so it doesnt slow the ui down?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original suggestion would have been to use a service however, upon researching it looks like that won't be the right direction to go.
from: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

> Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main
>   thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is
>   going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such
>   as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to
>   do that work. More information on this can be found in Processes and
>   Threads. The IntentService class is available as a standard
>   implementation of Service that has its own thread where it schedules
>   its work to be done.
>   I may  be possible to use the Service in the "intent service" way but that seems like it's not a common way to use it.

Based on the threads link from the link above I would suggest a worker thread, you can find it here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html

As long as you're not planning on updating UI elements from it, if so there are additional suggestions/links under the worker thread heading that describe additional considerations.

Good luck, I hope this helps

Comment: thank you :) you mean create a thread to play the sound like this? new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
//play sound here

Comment: Sorry, I don't get on stackoverflow enough, I'm glad you were able to get it with my suggestion.